# Visual Studio 2017 is busy while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2017

[image]

After I close my app VS freezes and I can't do anything. I must close VS process. Any solutions?

Comment: Does this error occur with any app you attempt to run? Does it only occur when debugging, or does it occur when running the app without debugging? Is there any code in your project which could cause this error?

Comment: Please see [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send feedback in Visual Studio 2017. You need Microsoft account to report a problem.

See the image below:

[image]

Here are the steps on [how to report a problem with visual studio 2017](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017.md).

Comment: Url is no longer valid, use [this to report an issue with visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#:~:text=In%20Visual%20Studio%2C%20select%20the,Send%20Feedback%20%3E%20Report%20a%20Problem.).